# CakePHP 2.4 Auth->login() always return FALSE

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am working on a simple login application with cake 2.4 for my mom. here is the code for User model.

```
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel{
        public $validate = array(
                'username' => array(
                        'required' => array(
                                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                                'message' => 'A username is required'
                        )
                ),
                'password' => array(
                        'required' => array(
                                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                                'message' => 'A password is required'
                        )
                )
        );

        public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
                if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
                        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
                        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                        $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
                        );
                }
                return true;
        }
}
```

My UsersController code is...

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
        public $helpers = array('Html','Form');

        public function beforeFilter(){
                parent::beforeFilter();
                $this->Auth->allow('add');
        }
        public function add(){
                if($this->request->is('post')){
                        $this->User->create();
                        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                        }
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
        }
        public function login(){
                $this->layout = 'mlayout';
                if($this->request->is('post')){
                        debug($this->Auth->login());
                        var_dump($this->request->data);
                        if($this->Auth->login()){
                                $this->Session->setFlash('Logged In');
                                //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                        }else{
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario o Contraseña invalido, intentelo de nuevo.'));
                        }
                }
        }
        public function logout(){
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
}
```

AppController code:

```
class AppController extends Controller{

        public $components = array('Session',
                'Auth' => array(
                        'loginRedirect' => array(
                                'controller' => 'homes',
                                'action' => 'index'
                        ),
                        'logoutRedirect' => array(
                                'controller' => 'homes',
                                'action' => 'index'
                        ),
                        'authorize' => 'controller'
                )
        );

        public function beforeFilter(){
                $this->Auth->allow('index','view','login');
        }
}
```

Login.ctp

```
<table id="formtable">
    <form id="UserForm" method="post" action="/mercadito/users/login">
        <tr>
        <td align="right">Login -> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right">Contraseña -> </td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="ENTRAR" style="width: 100px; height: 30px;"/></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

---

```
debug($this->Auth->login()) returns: /app/Controller/UsersController.php (line 23) false

var_dump() returns: array(2) { ["username"]=> string(9) "admin" ["password"]=> string(9) "admin" }
```

This happens every time. I changed the location of `allow->('login')`, then I checked if my password was well hashed, and it was. But the problem persists.

Comment: Note that it also returns false if you are already logged in!

Comment: Yes, that happened to me sometime ago, try logout and then login again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $this->Form->input() method to create your fields, because the fields which Cake would expect should be like:

```
data[User][username]
data[User][password]
```

So your code should be like:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Login'));?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

I bet that if you try with empty password it should let you in, since it always crypt the empty variable :)

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the Component-Variable in your

> AppController:

---

```
class AppController extends Controller{

    public $components = array('Session',
            'Auth' => array(
                'loginRedirect' => array(
                      'controller' => 'homes',
                      'action' => 'index'
                 ),
                 'logoutRedirect' => array(
                      'controller' => 'homes',
                      'action' => 'index'
                 ),
                 'authorize' => 'controller'
                 ),
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => array(
                        'className' => 'Simple',
                        'hashType' => 'sha256'
                )
            )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you all for responding! I tried everything you said but still obtain 'FALSE' all the time. :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in database for password its `varchar(40)` or `varchar(40+)` because cakephp's hashing algorithm will generate string of `36 characters`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you accepted the wrong answer. Since you're trying to authenticate using the **email** address, you should change the name attribute in your login.ctp like so:

```
<input type="text" name="username" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;"/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="email" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what fixed it for me was changing $this->alias to User, so beforeSave() now looks like

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
}
return true; }
```